# Show Different prices for store views (magento prices at store view level)

Tags: magento-1.9, price, store-view

How can we setup different prices for different stores in a website

can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 2):

Prices can be set at global or website level.
I remember seeing some extensions that allow you to set different prices at store view level, but they are risky and not sure if they cover every aspect.
If you really want you can find them with a simple search for "magento prices at store view level" or something similar.

I strongly recommend not touching this part and if you want different prices at store view levels, just create multiple websites and assign store views to these websites. This way you will use the "out of the box" features.

Comment: thanks @marius , but when we create multiple websites multiple domains should be there. We have only one website but wanted to show different prices accordingly to store-views(city wise)

Comment: you can still have all the websites in the same domain. The only thing you need to change is the store switcher to take into account all the store views, not only the ones in the current website.